# Why there are three reactions at fixed beam in F.B.D?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

It is fixed so no reactions will be present, then how three reactions at fixed beam in F.B.D?

[image]

In F.B.D, we draw two reactions and moment reaction at fixed beam:

[image]

Why there are three reactions at fixed beam in F.B.D?

Comment: It would be helpful to spell out acronyms, maybe just for the first occurrence.

Comment: Manny, in statics it is common knowledge that FBD stands for Free Body Diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as referred to in the comments, do define all TLAs before they are used. SE doesn't exist only to provide insight to the acronymistically hip.

The three forces are:

1. Normal force (if its on the bench and not massless then there has to be a normal force)
2. Pivoting force (the weight being offset from where it is resting will act to rotate it)
3. Fudge force (as the object is fixed it cannot be rotating so there must exist a force that counteracts the rotation and keeps it fixed in place).

Comment: What is a TLA? I don’t see it in the question.

Comment: Three Letter Acronym

Comment: OK Paul, but in statics it is common knowledge that FBD stands for Free Body Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

In statics there are two requirements for equilibrium, (1) the algebraic sum of all the external forces acting on the beam have to be zero and (2) the sum of the moments about any location on the beam have to be zero. The first requirement prevents translation motion of the beam. The second prevents rotation.

In the free body diagram the external forces are the applied loads, $F$ in your diagram, and the reaction forces where the beam is supported, $R_x$ and $R_y$ in your diagram.

The number of possible reaction forces depends on the type of support. There are three basic types (1) pins, (2) rollers, and (3) fixed supports. Only a vertical reaction is possible at a roller supports. Vertical and horizontal reactions are possible at pin and fixed supports. Your support is fixed and therefore you have two possible reaction forces, vertical and horizontal, $R_y$ and $R_x$ in your diagram. The moment at the fixed support is not normally referred to as a “reaction”. The term is normally reserved to describe forces.

Now as regards to your particular beam. You need a reaction force $R_x$ to the left (opposite the direction shown) to equal the applied force to the right of $Fcos60$. You need an upward reaction $R_y$ (as shown) to equal the applied downward force of $Fsin60$. Finally you need a counter-clockwise moment $M$ at the support to equal the clockwise moment of the force $F$. There is insufficient information on the diagram to make that determination.

Hope this helps.